# Equivalent of a 'While True' loop in Flask: how to do it?

Tags: loops, flask, while-loop

Spending my evenings hobby coding a topography quiz for my daughter. Leveraging the web and Stack Overflow resources, I got an API running on https://ac1976.pythonanywhere.com/api/wereld Hit it and the server will respond with a JSON object comprised of a random country / capital combination, together with a list of 'wrong' answers for the capital. The wrong answers are based on distance to the (correct) capital and are also randomized. So Tokyo won't show up as an answer for the capital of Belgium, but Paris and London may.

On topic: now building a flask app that fetches a response from the aforementioned API, and creates a multiple choice quiz game asking for the capital of the random country, and giving the user 4 multiple choice options.

My main route to do all of this works, and looks like this:

```
@app.route('/api/continent/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def quiz():

if request.method == "GET":

    quiz = Game('wereld')
    country = quiz.country
    answers = quiz.answers
    session['capital'] = quiz.capital

    return render_template('quiz.html', a1=answers[0], a2=answers[1], a3=answers[2], a4=answers[3], country=country)
    
else:
    
    answer = request.form['subject']

    if answer == session.get('capital'):
    
        return render_template('antwoord.html', answer="Jaaaaa...")

    else:

        return render_template('antwoord.html', answer="Neee..")
```

So on hitting the route initially, the server initializes the class Game, which is essentially a wrapper to catch the response from the API and parcel the response with methods for each of the data points we need: country, answers, and capital. These quiz items are stored in similarly named variables country, answers and capital. Country (in the form of a question) and answers (as 4 separate buttons) are used in the HTML template file, presented on hitting the route.

If the user presses one of the four buttons, the second part of the route logic figures out whether the answer was right, or wrong, and sends back a new html view telling the user the answer was right....or wrong.

Okay. All makes sense, right?

Here's my question. How do I autodirect, after say 1 second, back to the 'top of the if loop' so that the code auto refetches a new response from the API, to play another round? I tried to put a simple "While True:" on top of the if / else loop, which works my original terminal version of this quiz...but Flask is not having it. I understand why (it needs a 'GET') but....how to cause a new one?

thanks for your thoughts / guidance / pointing me in the right direction

Arie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a meta refresh tag within the header of the HTML page.
After the defined time has expired, you will be redirected to the specified URL.

It would then look something like this.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url={{url_for('quiz', _external=True)}}" />
```

If you want to use JavaScript, a variant with a timeout would also be possible.

```
const uri = {{url_for('quiz') | tojson}}; 
setTimeout(() => window.location.replace(uri), 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you @Detlef for your guidance. I tried both approaches and both work very well. Is there an important reason for implementing the JavaScript variant versus the refresh meta tag? Your suggestion has me realize it would be easier to implement this quiz with somewhat catchy front end design for mobiles: first view is the quiz with answers (page filling buttons), second screen is red or green flashing view indicating good/wrong answer, and back to the next quiz q using the JavaScript or metatag approach. What's best practice...or save to be agnostic?

Comment: The meta variant is the simplest to implement. If you have some knowledge of javascript, it is even possible to implement the entire application in this language. Depending on whether, for example, you want to display a timer that is running down and the response is to be given in the time span, you will be dependent on JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to go one step further and use one of the trendy frameworks such as react, vue or svelte, your approach, by separating the frontend and backend, is a good start. However, keep in mind that you have to host the result on a platform, which may pose problems for you with pythonanywhere.

Comment: I have read your explanation again and unfortunately I have to tell you that I have no experience with purely mobile applications. So I can't give you any tips in this regard, but it would also be possible to create such an application with react native, for example.

Comment: Thanks! Have been learning Python for a while now and these are my first steps with Flask, HTML (and your JavaScript fix was my first ever). My plan is to develop (the HTML parts of) this now properly working Flask for mobile (or better: mobile oriented) by using some standard Bootstrap, and host it on another PythonAnywhere location. That should give my kid a nice app to toy with. Just two views: the question and multiple choice buttons she can touch, and quick flashing red/green screen for the answer. Loop it and be done! In v2 I'll figure out how to keep track of scores...thx!